Retrieve old jobs from IBM qcs after later qiskit changes
I don't know anymore how can I retrieve old jobs from qiskit via the jupyter notebook. When I try to use the commands
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
service = QiskitRuntimeService()
job = service.job("JOB_ID")

I get the error message
RequestsApiError: '401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://auth.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/users/loginWithToken. Login failed., Error code: 3446.'

This is the first time I encounter this error. I used to access without problems from the notebook using my already saved credentials, but apparently many things have changed recently and now I cannot access anymore to the past jobs.
How can Ifix this?

If you are running locally, this means your token might not be properly saved into the qiskit-ibm.json file that stores your token information. To fix this, run:
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
QiskitRuntimeService.save_account(channel='ibm_quantum', token='your-token-here', overwrite=True)

where your-token-here is the latest token generated from your IBMQ account.
